# Potentiostat circuit biased with three independent sources

Tags: potentiometer, homework

How might a potentiostat circuit be designed such that it is biased with three independent AC sources, the reference electrode is biased at $$\varepsilon = 2sin(\omega t) + 3sin(\omega t) + 4sin(2\omega t)$$

and

$$Rref = 1k\Omega$$

Note: the solution returned for the problem only mentions which electrodes are capped, circled or arrowed: AE, WE, and RE respectively.

Comment: What does \$ \epsilon=2+3( \omega t)+4( \omega t) \$ means? Are those numbers just multiplying the \$\omega t\$? Or is it something else?

Comment: I edited the post. They describe the three voltage sources, unit is volts. No other information was provided other than that. I found this to be helpful: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/sinusoidal-waveform.html

Comment: Are those power supplies really connected like that? It seems that they are completely floating and will have no influence on the amp op or the potentiostat.

Comment: I see what you mean, could you show a different design?

Comment: Since there is only one wire coming from the source section no current can flow. You should probably have a ground symbol at the bottom of the three signal sources.

Comment: @stexacc Are you looking for how to implement that circuit in real life? What exactly is the question in this post?

Comment: Not implementing IRL, just trying to understand. I think I omitted the ground at some iteration. I have made notes of the comments.

Comment: Is the  '2' signal in your first equation meant to be a direct voltage source (0 rad/s)? If so, it won't get through C1.

Comment: And the output of the op amp is shorted to ground in your schematic

Comment: I will repost my solution after reviewing the design properly. In the mean time, will leave the question up because I want to see other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As i pointed out, you have a whole node floating in your circuit and that wouldn't make much sense (or work), it would be just as completely eliminating all elements V1, V2, V3 and C1 from the schematic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO2q27.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I made edits to the post to correct for the floating node. My question is how to design the circuit to bias the reference electrode per the specification